# Javascript: loading image in memory & displaying in a new document

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I need to create a new document on the fly and display an image in it. The url of the image is passed as a variable into the function.

```
newWin('folder/image.jpg');
```

The codes of this function:

```
function newWin(url){
    var strg = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>';
    strg += '<img src ="'+url+'"></body></html>';
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=600, height=400");
    myWindow.document.writeln(strg);
}
```

There is more to the contents of the new document that what is displayed here. 
The image doesn't load all the time or loads on 3rd or 4th attempt. How do I pre-load the image in the memory so that it appears instantly? I am not sure how to implement new image() in this situation. Kindly help!

Comment: Why not just use window.open? you can pass the path to the image and also specify window size AFAIK. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: What does your network panel tells when the image is not loading?

Answer (score 2):

You can either

1. Preload the image with an Image object and hope the browser will cache it
2. Preload the image data, convert it into base64, and put that data into the new window's html.

Method 2 is alot of code and really only necessary when the preloading has to work 100% of the time.

So here is method 1:

```
function preloadWin(url){
    var img = new Image()
    img.src = url
    img.onload = function (){
        newWin(url)
    }
}
```

Call `preloadWin('folder/image.jpg')` and it should open up the window once the image is loaded.

Comment: To avoid to count on caching, you can even directly append the loaded HTMLImage created in main window to the new window:  `function newWin(url){
    var strg = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body></body></html>';
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=600, height=400");
    myWindow.document.writeln(strg);
    myWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
}`